# How to pull "Last Trade Date" data from Yahoo! Finance API within Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, yahoo-finance

Using Visual Basic, I am attempting to pull "Last Trade Date" data from the Yahoo! Finance API for CSV by referencing a stock's ticker symbol within Excel.

The [Yahoo! Finance API](http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/) **last trade date**  is appended to the URL as "&f=**d1**" with **ticker** being substituted for whatever stock exchange symbol is passed to StockQuote() within Excel (i.e. GOOG, GE).

When entering a ticker symbol into a cell and, in turn, referencing that cell with StockQuote(), I am receiving a **#VALUE!** error.

#### #VALUE! error screenshot from Excel

[image: #VALUE! error screenshot from Excel]

I realize that using the **As Double** data type for the StockQuote() function may not be appropriate for retrieving date data. Replacing Double with the **Integer**, **Long**, and **Date** data types within my current block of code have presented a #VALUE! error as well.

I am working in a macro-enabled sheet and have placed the Visual Basic code inside a module.

Will someone explain the source of the #VALUE! error and how I might revise the code below to retrieve the last trade date for a given ticker symbol when utilizing the Yahoo! Finance API?

```
Option Explicit

Function StockQuote(ByVal ticker As String) As Double
Dim url As String
Dim lastDate As Double
Dim http As Object

url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & ticker & "&f=d1"

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", url, False
http.Send

StockQuote = http.responseText
Set http = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling your function from a Sub instead of from the worksheet will give you a better idea of what's going wrong.

In this case the error is "Type Mismatch" on the line:

```
StockQuote = http.responseText
```

This is because (as you suspected) you've flagged the function's return type as `Double`, whereas `http.responseText` is of type `String`.
Note that *the return value actually contains quotes* so you might want to remove those.

```
Function StockQuote(ByVal ticker As String) As Double
    Dim url As String
    Dim lastDate As Double
    Dim http As Object, rv

    url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & ticker & "&f=d1"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.Send

    rv = http.responseText
    StockQuote = CDate(Trim(Replace(rv, """", "")))

    Set http = Nothing
End Function
```